# What is the word for doing an act and not knowing you're doing it until its done?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Like standing in one area of a room and then the next thing you know you’re across the room stuck in a weird fighting stance position, Because you were taking something from someone and you didn't realize you were doing this until they called your name.
Kind of feels like you were going through a tunnel.
Like unintentional tunnel vision.

Comment: I think this is commonly called a "blackout".

Comment: What you did was done *unconsciously*

Comment: Do you refer to a "knee-jerk reaction" (reflex reaction) or to "work blind" (i.e. without guidance, proper information, ...) ?

Comment: When you suddenly concentrate on your driving again after daydreaming for a few miles, it's often said that you've been operating on your 'reptilian brain' (auto-pilot).

Answer (score 2):

This might be called *[automatism](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/automatism)*:-

> 1. the state or quality of being automatic; mechanical or involuntary action
> 2. (Law) law philosophy the explanation of an action, or of action in general, as determined by the physiological states of the individual,
>      admissible in law as a defence when the physiological state is
>      involuntary, as in sleepwalking [Collins English Dictionary]

explained further [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/automatism):-

> An involuntary act such as sleepwalking that is performed in a state
>   of unconsciousness. The subject does not act voluntarily and is not
>   fully aware of his or her actions while in a state of automatism.
>   Automatism has been used as a defense to show that a defendant lacked
>   the requisite mental state for the commission of a crime. A defense
>   based on automatism asserts that there was no act in the legal sense
>   because at the time of the alleged crime, the defendant had no psychic
>   awareness or volition. Some American jurisdictions have recognized
>   automatism as a complete, Affirmative Defense to most criminal
>   charges. An Insanity Defense, by comparison, asserts that the accused
>   possessed psychic awareness or volition, but at the time of the
>   offense, the accused possessed a mental disorder or defect that caused
>   them to commit the offense or prevented them from understanding the
>   wrongness of the offense. [West's Encyclopedia of Law]

Answer (score 1):

[*Fugue state*, sometimes called *dissociation*,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugue_state) describes a psychotic state where this happens, as opposed to the sort of [*zoning out*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/zone+out) that happens when you're commuting, for instance, and realize you've gotten home without really recalling the intervening trip.

Answer (score 0):

Inadvertently done. It means unintentionally done, which is about as close as I can get.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is known colloquially as a

> **reflex action**, *n.* an action performed independently of the will, as an automatic response to a sensory stimulus; (more widely) **an action that is automatic, unthinking, or instinctive**; also in extended use and *fig.*

["reflex, adj.". OED Online. December 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/160938?rskey=1T1VsJ&result=2&isAdvanced=false (accessed December 20, 2015). Bold emphasis mine.]

An example of the colloquial use:

[image]

From *Faithfully Yours*, Lou Tabakow, Start Classics, Jun 13, 2014.